# Example reports for mixed-model analysis using lmer in biology, psychology and medicine?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, references

As the general consensus seems to be to use mixed-models via `lmer()` in R instead of classical ANOVA (for the often cited reasons, like unbalanced designs, crossed random effects etc.), I would like to give it a try with my data. However I am worried that I would be able to "sell" this approach to my supervisor (who is expecting classical analysis with a p-value in the end) or later to the reviewers.

Could you recommend some nice examples of published articles that used mixed-models or `lmer()` for different designs like repeated-measures or multiple within- and between-subject designs for the field biology, psychology, medicine?

Comment: Also it would be nice to have some pointers to according references that are considered crucial to cite

Comment: On the [lme4 project](http://lme4.R-forge.R-project.org/) page, there is a [collection of articles and other research](http://lme4.R-forge.R-project.org/bib/lme4bib.html) using `nlme` or `lme4`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update 3 (May, 2013):** Another really good paper on mixed models in Psychology was released in the Journal of Memory and Language (although I do not agree with the authors conclusions on how to obtain *p*-values, see package `afex` instead). It very nicely discusses on how to specify the random effects structure. **Go read it!**

Barr, D. J., Levy, R., Scheepers, C., & Tily, H. J. (2013). [Random effects structure for confirmatory hypothesis testing: Keep it maximal](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/barr-etal-2013-jml.pdf). *Journal of Memory and Language*, 68(3), 255–278. doi:10.1016/j.jml.2012.11.001

---

**Update 2 (July, 2012):** A paper advocating the use in (Social) Psychology when there are crossed (e.g., participants and items) random effects.
The big thing is: It shows how to obtain p-values using the [pbkrtest package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html):

Judd, C. M., Westfall, J., & Kenny, D. A. (2012). Treating stimuli as a random factor in social psychology: A new and comprehensive solution to a pervasive but largely ignored problem. *Journal of Personality and Social Psychology*, 103(1), 54–69. doi:10.1037/a0028347
[(only available as a Word .doc)](http://dionysus.psych.wisc.edu/lit/InPress/Judd%20crossed_random.docx)

Jake Westfall told me (per mail) that an alternative for obtaining p-values to the advocated Kenward-Rogers approximation (used in pbkrtest) is the (less optimal) Satterthwaite approximation, which can be found in the [MixMod](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MixMod/) package using the `anovaTab` function.

*Small update to last update:* My R package [`afex`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html) contains function `mixed()` to conveniently obtain p-values for all effects in a mixed model. Alternatively, the [`car`](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) package now also obtains p-values for mixed models in `Anova()` using `test.statistic = "F"`

---

**UPDATE1:** Another paper describing lme4

Kliegl, R., Wei, P., Dambacher, M., Yan, M., & Zhou, X. (2011). [Experimental effects and individual differences in linear mixed models: estimating the relationship between spatial, object, and attraction effects in visual attention.](http://www.frontiersin.org/Journal/DownloadFile.ashx?pdf=1&FileId=%201226&articleId=%202124&Version=%201&ContentTypeId=21&FileName=%20fpsyg-01-00238.pdf) *Frontiers in Quantitative Psychology and Measurement*, 1, 238. doi:10.3389/fpsyg.2010.00238

---

**Original Response:**

I do not have a number of examples, only one (see below), but know some paper you should cite from Psychology/Cognitive Sciences. The most important one is definitely:

Baayen, R. H., Davidson, D. J., & Bates, D. M. (2008). Mixed-effects modeling with crossed random effects for subjects and items. *Journal of Memory and Language*, 59(4), 390–412. doi:10.1016/j.jml.2007.12.005

Another one from Baayen is:

Baayen, R. H., & Milin, P. (2010). Analyzing Reaction Times. *International Journal of Psychological Research*, 3(2), 12–28.

I actually totally liked his book, too, which also has a nice introductory chapter on mixed model (and is pretty cheap for a stats book):
Baayen, R. H. (2008). [Analyzing linguistic data : a practical introduction to statistics using R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521709180). Cambridge, UK; New York: Cambridge University Press.

I probably guess he also has a lot of papers using `lme4`, but as my main interest is not psycholinguistics, you might wanna check his [homepage](http://www.ualberta.ca/~baayen/publications.html).

From my field (reasoning), I know of this one paper that uses `lme4`:

Fugard, A. J. B., Pfeifer, N., Mayerhofer, B., & Kleiter, G. D. (2011). [How people interpret conditionals: Shifts toward the conditional event.](http://www.pfeifer-research.de/pdf/JEP_Dice10.pdf) *Journal of Experimental Psychology: Learning, Memory, and Cognition*, 37(3), 635–648. doi:10.1037/a0022329

(although I have the feeling they use a likelihood ratio test to compare models which only differ in the fixed parameters, which I have heard is not the correct way. I think you should use AIC instead.)

Comment: Draft of **Analyzing linguistic data : a practical introduction to statistics using R** is available [here](http://www.ualberta.ca/~baayen/publications/baayenCUPstats.pdf).

Comment: I also had the pdf, but as the book was really cheap I bought it and am really happy. It is kind of easier to read if you have it as a book.

Comment: @Henrik you say LRTs should not be used to compare models that differ only in fixed effects, do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Matt I have this information from a discussion with Mike Lawrence from the `ez` package: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ez4r/GQTEtNziRwE
Mike cites Pinheiro & Bates (2000) for it, see the link.

Answer (score 12):

This is a highly-cited paper on mixed models for ecology and evolution:

- Bolker et al. (2009) Generalized linear mixed models: a practical guide for ecology and evolution *Trends in Ecology & Evolution* Vol. 24 pp127-135 ([PDF](http://facecouncil.org/puf/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Bolker-et-al-2009-TREE.pdf)) ([from ScienceDirect with links to Supplementary Content](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169534709000196)).

Answer (score 7):

The following article endeavours to promote the use of multilevel modelling in social science settings:

- Bliese, P. D. & Ployhart, R. E. (2002). Growth Modeling Using Random
  Coefficient Models: Model Building, Testing, and Illustrations, Organizational Research Methods, Vol. 5 No. 4, October 2002 362-387. [PDF](http://www.ltdalarna.se/upload/784/Growth%20model.pdf)

To quote the abstract:

> In this article, the authors illustrate how random coefficient
>   modeling can be used to develop growth models for the analysis of
>   longitudinal data. In contrast to previous discussions of random
>   coefficient models, this article provides step-by-step guidance using
>   a model comparison framework. By approaching the modeling this way,
>   the authors are able to build off a regression foundation and
>   progressively estimate and evaluate more complex models. In the model
>   comparison framework, the article illustrates the value of using
>   likelihood tests to contrast alternative models (rather than the
>   typical reliance on tests of significance involving individual
>   parameters), and it provides code in the open-source language R to
>   allow readers to replicate the results. The article concludes with
>   practical guidelines for estimating growth models.

An examination of the articles listed on Google Scholar as citing this [paper suggest several other useful leads](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=2184353176304389111&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en).

Comment: This paper looks really interesting. Unfortunately it only uses `lme` from `nlme` instead of `lmer` from `lme4`. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

An excellent example of using mixed models in ecology is:

- "[Demography and management of the invasive species *Hypericum
  perforatum*. I.  Using multi-level mixed-effects models for
  characterizing growth, survival and fecundity in a long-term data
  set](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2664.2003.00821.x/full)" (Buckely, Briese and Rees 2003).

Unfortunately it uses older R libraries.

Answer (score 4):

I am reading Zuur, A. F., Ieno, E. N., Walker, N., Saveliev, A. A., & Smith, G. M. (2009). [Mixed effects models and extensions in ecology with R](http://www.springer.com/life+sciences/ecology/book/978-0-387-87457-9). New York, NY: Springer Science+Business Media, LLC. It is written for ecologists, so the stats are fairly easy to follow; I think it would be useful for people from other disciplines, such as medicine or psychology too. There are many case studies included, and each has a detailed section on how to best write up the stats in a paper.