# Compute partial $\eta^2$ for all fixed effects anovas from a lme4 model

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

*Disclamer: I wasn't sure where to post this question: CV or SO, but eventually decided to try here first*

I've been asked by one of the reviewers to add effects sizes (preferably $\eta^2_p$ which is standard in my field) for all the $F$ and $t$ tests reported in auxiliary analyses of my paper.

To be specific I'm mentioning a significant 4-way interaction (`A:B:C:response`) between fixed effects of a `anova(lmer.model)` call and explaining it with simple interactions and estimated marginal means using `emmeans` package and `pairs()` function (reproducible exemplary code is attached below).

I'm aware that there at least a debate on whether or not computing effect sizes for mixed effects models makes sense, but I'd like to satisfy the reviewer without any further discussion.

I've come across some sources mentioning effect sizes in the context of LMEM but I don't feel strong enough with math to understand it.

**My question here is twofold:**

1. If there is **any citable** way to produce $\eta^2$, $\eta^2_p$ or
   $\omega^2$ for anovas $F$ tests **how can I do it**? An `R` package
   / function / script would be great help. Eventually hints for
   retrieving crucial values from a `lmer()` object in order to get
   eff.sizes by hand would be helpful as well

   Eg. I know that $\eta^2 = {SS_{Effect}}/{SS_{Total}}$ and
   `anova(lmer_obj)` gives $SS_{Effect}$ but no $SS_{Total}$ and I have
   no clue how to get it with `R`
2. If there is **no way** computing it - what paper (not blog post) can
   I cite when answering the reviewer why I insisted on skipping effect
   sizes.

Note that I'm not interested in random effects *per se* - I defined a maximum justified by design structure of random effects only to control more error variance and my only interest are the fixed effects - namely Fs from the anova table and corresponding marginal means.

Some exemplary results (corresponding to a real data structure by with random values) are as follow:

The `A:B:C:response` interaction is significant at $F(1; 12082,1)=4,60; p=.032, (\eta^2_p=xxx$)

```
> anova(m0)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value  Pr(>F)  
A               1.6717  1.6717     1   134.7  0.4210 0.51755  
B               0.1375  0.1375     1 11860.0  0.0346 0.85238  
C               7.1708  7.1708     1   133.5  1.8058 0.18129  
response        3.7775  3.7775     1 12070.3  0.9513 0.32940  
A:B             1.1291  1.1291     1 11872.8  0.2844 0.59387  
A:C             3.2427  3.2427     1   121.1  0.8166 0.36796  
B:C             4.1048  4.1048     1   121.8  1.0337 0.31130  
A:response      0.0000  0.0000     1 12080.8  0.0000 0.99828  
B:response      4.2350  4.2350     1 12078.9  1.0665 0.30176  
C:response      1.6567  1.6567     1 12082.3  0.4172 0.51834  
A:B:C           8.5249  8.5249     1   131.4  2.1469 0.14525  
A:B:response    0.8765  0.8765     1   132.0  0.2207 0.63926  
A:C:response    1.5150  1.5150     1   119.5  0.3815 0.53797  
B:C:response    0.5921  0.5921     1   122.5  0.1491 0.70005  
A:B:C:response 18.2803 18.2803     1 12082.1  4.6036 0.03192 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Follow-up comparisons show that the interaction of `A:B:C` is only valid for `response=0`: $F(1; 809,32)=4,68; p=.031, (\eta^2_p=xxx$)

```
> joint_tests(m0, by="response")
Note: D.f. calculations have been disabled because the number of observations exceeds 3000.
To enable adjustments, set emm_options(pbkrtest.limit = 12292) or larger,
but be warned that this may result in large computation time and memory use.
response = no:
 model term df1      df2 F.ratio p.value
 A            1   858.01   0.161  0.6884
 B            1 12177.54   0.530  0.4664
 C            1   837.27   0.212  0.6453
 A:B          1   785.54   0.365  0.5457
 A:C          1   507.23   0.872  0.3509
 B:C          1   476.41   0.145  0.7035
 A:B:C        1   809.32   4.680  0.0308

response = yes:
 model term df1      df2 F.ratio p.value
 A            1   184.95   0.361  0.5489
 B            1 11853.63   0.601  0.4381
 C            1   182.47   3.237  0.0736
 A:B          1   177.43   0.000  0.9874
 A:C          1   130.20   0.072  0.7882
 B:C          1   123.71   1.465  0.2285
 A:B:C        1   178.96   0.235  0.6281
```

In my real dataset there are more predicted effects but the idea is still the same. I'm reporting $F$s or $t$s following *APA 6 ed.* rules and i'm being asked to add some sort of effect sizes to them.

Any help with this matter will be greatly appreciated.

**Full reproducible example**

```
###############################################################
#Simulate data replicating the structure of a real life example
###############################################################

library(AlgDesign) #for generating all levels a factorial design)

set.seed(2)
df <-gen.factorial(c(16,2,2,2,100), factors = "all", 
                   varNames = c("rep", "A", "B", "C", "Subject"))
df$rep <- as.numeric(df$rep)
df$Subject <- as.numeric(df$Subject)
logRT <- rnorm(n=12800, m=7, sd=2)
trialno<- rep(1:128, times = 100)
response <- factor(sample(0:1, 12800, prob = c(0.3, 0.7), replace = T), 
                   labels= c("no", "yes"))

#Simulate some values to drop (set as missings) due to extremly low latency
missingRTs<- as.logical(sample(0:1, 12800, prob = c(0.96, 0.04), replace = T))
logRT[missingRTs==1] <- NA

df <- cbind(df, logRT, trialno, response)
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]

##########################
#Setup model with afex
########################## 

library(afex)
m0 <- mixed(logRT ~ A*B*C*response + (A*B*C*response||Subject), 
            data = df, return = 'merMod', method = "S", expand_re = TRUE)

##########################
#Get results for paper
########################## 

anova(m0)

emm_options(lmerTest.limit = 12292)
em0<-emmeans(m0, ~A*B*C*response)

joint_tests(m0, by="response")
joint_tests(m0, by=c("response", "B"))
```

Comment: checking out the links from googling "site:https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/ "effect size" eta" now ...

Comment: I suggest to not report standardized effect for mixed models and instead report unstandardized effect sizes or alternatively explain that it is simply not possible. See my longer response with pointers to literature here: https://afex.singmann.science/forums/topic/compute-effect-sizes-for-mixed-objects#post-295

Comment: @BenBolker I googled that but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: I think @Henrik's answer is definitive.  I was going to point you to his `afex` package, since there are some functions in there that appear to do a bit with partial eta-squared, but since he has responded himself ...

Comment: What is SO you refer to in the disclaimer?

Comment: StackOverflow - programming oriented statexchange

Comment: @BenBolker I wonder what you think about Johnson's method, especially about using the semi-partial $R^2$ values that Jaeger et al. derived for this method (see my A). Also, do you have an opinion on the *other* $R^2$ statistic that Jaeger et al. developed by utilizing the penalized quasi-likelihood estimation method based on linearization (it's in the same paper https://doi.org/10.1080/02664763.2016.1193725).

Comment: I'm don't really know; I'm not *that* interested in these kinds of effect-size measures: I think they're useful, but I know it's a messy question. I do think the $R^2$ measures are reasonable.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the quick response and evaluation. So I guess one could argue that there are citable papers (in the sense that they exist and that the effect-size measures therein are well derived) showing how to calculate effect-sizes measures that are analogous to the ANOVA-effect-size measures mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Yes. It will depend what the reviewers are asking for: if they are both ignorant and stubborn (i.e. "you need to give us an $\eta^2$, we don't care that no-one knows how to calculate it") then life could be hard.  I really haven't looked to see how sensible/difficult the semi-partial marginal $R^2$ values are ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, I think @Henrik's answer [here](https://afex.singmann.science/forums/topic/compute-effect-sizes-for-mixed-objects#post-295) is sound and should (at least in excerpts) be stated on this site:

> The fact that calculating a global measure of model fit (such as R2)
>   is already riddled with complications and that no simple single number
>   can be found, should be a hint that doing so for a subset of the model
>   parameters (i.e., main-effects or interactions) is even more
>   difficult. Given this, I would not recommend to try finding a measure
>   of standardized effect sizes for mixed models.

This is what he suggests to answer to a reviewer like yours (although the type-I-error argument mainly applies to designs with [crossed (random) grouping factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/136579)):

> Unfortunately, due to the way that variance is partitioned in linear
>   mixed models (e.g., [Rights & Sterba, 2019](https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000184)), there does not exist
>   an agreed upon way to calculate standard effect sizes for individual
>   model terms such as main effects or interactions. We nevertheless
>   decided to primarily employ mixed models in our analysis, because
>   mixed models are vastly superior in controlling for Type I errors than
>   alternative approaches and consequently results from mixed models are
>   more likely to generalize to new observations (e.g., [Barr, Levy,
>   Scheepers, & Tily, 2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jml.2012.11.001); [Judd, Westfall, & Kenny, 2012](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0028347)).
>   Whenever possible, we report unstandardized effect sizes which is in
>   line with general recommendation of how to report effect sizes (e.g.,
>   [Pek & Flora, 2018](https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000126)).

That being said, personally, I like the $R^2$ measures of [Johnson (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.12225) which are extensions to the corresponding versions of [Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x):

The *marginal R squared* ($R^2_m$) can be interpreted as the variance explained by all fixed effects in the model, the *conditional R squared* ($R^2_c$) estimates the variance explained by all fixed effects and all random effects in the model taken together.

Below I show how we can obtain these $R^2$ measures from `lmerMod` and `lmerModLmerTest` objects via the `MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM()` function.

```
library("MuMIn")

r.squaredGLMM(m0)
#              R2m        R2c
# [1,] 0.001241324 0.01762294
```

Additionally, the *semi-partial (marginal) R squared* describes the variance explained by each fixed effect adjusted for the other predictors in the model. [Jaeger, Edwards, Das, and Sen (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1080/02664763.2016.1193725) show how one can calculate this measure as a Wald statistic of the desired subset of fixed effects.

We can calculate the semi-partial R squared for each fixed effect via the `r2glmm::r2beta()` function. Note that you should get the `r2glmm` package from GitHub as the CRAN version is not up to date (accessed 2019-12-08) and misses important functionality.

```
# devtools::install_github('bcjaeger/r2glmm')
library("r2glmm")

r2beta(m0, method = "nsj")
#            Effect   Rsq upper.CL lower.CL
# 1           Model 0.001    0.004    0.001
# 16 A:B:C:response 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 12          A:B:C 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 4               C 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 8             B:C 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 10     B:response 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 7             A:C 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 5        response 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 2               A 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 14   A:C:response 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 11     C:response 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 6             A:B 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 13   A:B:response 0.000    0.001    0.000
# 15   B:C:response 0.000    0.000    0.000
# 3               B 0.000    0.000    0.000
# 9      A:response 0.000    0.000    0.000
```

Comment: How can I compute the *semi-partial (marginal) R squared* in the case of an ANOVA? For instance, I would like the effect size for the whole factor (instead of each dummy code).

Comment: @mat Did you follow my advice and install the `r2glmm` package from GitHub (say, via `devtools::install_github('bcjaeger/r2glmm')`)? The latest GitHub version should do what you want.

Comment: I did so and it does not seems to work. I created a new post, please have a look: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574997/lmer-anova-effect-sizes