# Linear mixed-effects model equation for correlated and uncorrelated random slopes

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I've been asked to provide a linear equation for a `lme4:lmer()` model that I report in one paper.

I tried to adapt examples from http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer but this is not my area of expertise and I would like to avoid any guesswork.

Given a *repeated measurement* experiment dataset where:

- **A** and **B** are 2-level factors fully balanced within-subjects
- **C** is a dichotomous (*yes* or *no* response) independent variable
- **Y** is the outcome
- *The 3-way interaction within fixed effects is of main interest*

How can I write down a *regression style* statistical equation for two `lmer()` mixed-effects models where:

1. random slopes are correlated
   `lmer(Y ~ A*B*C + (A*B*C | Subj), data)`
2. random slopes are uncorrelated due to convergence errors
   `lmer(Y ~ A*B*C + (A*B*C || Subj), data)`

PS. Reproducible example of a dataset that simulates my real experiment is posted here: [Compute partial η2
for all fixed effects anovas from a lme4 model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/358927/133561)

Answer (score 2):

The variant with correlated random slopes is your model 1. The variant without correlation is not easily possible using `lmer`, due to `A` and `B` being categorical.

My package [`afex`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=afex) offers two solutions:

1. `lmer_alt` which is a wrapper for `lmer` that allows this. Note that in this case care should be taken that the factor codings are appropriate for interactions with categorical covriates (e.g., `"contr_sum"`).
2. `mixed(.., expand_re = TRUE)`. In your case:
   `mixed(Y ~ A*B*C + (A*B*C || Subj), data, expand_Re = TRUE)`.
   The benefit of using `mixed` is that it automatically uses appropriate orthogonal contrasts and calculates *p*-values for the effects.

Information on how `afex` achieves this is given in section **Expand Random Effects** in [`?afex::mixed`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/afex/topics/mixed).

Comment: I did not make myself clear here. I'm interested in  mathematical formula expression for those two models. I'm perfectly aware which model is which. I just don't know how to write it down a statistical equation (no R code)