# lmer anova effect sizes

Tags: mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme, effect-size

I would like to compute the *marginal R squared* for the whole factors from an anova table. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358927/compute-partial-eta2-for-all-fixed-effects-anovas-from-a-lme4-model/439842?noredirect=1#comment1061474_439842) post shows how to get the effect size for each fixed effect based on the `r2glmm` package but it does not seem to work to get the whole factor.

Here is an example:

```r
library(lmerTest)
library(r2glmm)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, 5),
                 score = sample(15),
                 gender = rep(c("male", "female", "other"), 5),
                 age = rep(c("teenager", "adult", "old"), each = 5))

mdl <- lmer(score ~ gender + age + (1|id), data = df)

df
#     id    score   gender  age
# 1   1     9       male    teenager
# 2   2     4       female  teenager
# 3   3     7       other   teenager
# 4   1     1       male    teenager
# 5   2     2       female  teenager
# 6   3    13       other   adult
# 7   1    11       male    adult
# 8   2     3       female  adult
# 9   3     8       other   adult
# 10  1    12       male    adult
# 11  2     5       female  old
# 12  3     6       other   old
# 13  1    15       male    old
# 14  2    10       female  old
# 15  3    14       other   old
```

Compute the anova table:

```r
anova(mdl)
# Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
#        Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value  Pr(>F)  
# gender  24.75  12.375     2    10  1.0081 0.39916  
# age     80.45  40.225     2    10  3.2770 0.08044 .
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would like to compute the effect sizes for `gender` and `age` factors from the above anova table.

I tried:

```r
r2beta(mdl, partial = TRUE)
#        Effect   Rsq upper.CL lower.CL
# 1       Model 0.407    0.761    0.172
# 2  gendermale 0.215    0.601    0.003
# 3 genderother 0.143    0.537    0.001
# 5 ageteenager 0.143    0.537    0.001
# 4      ageold 0.027    0.377    0.000
```

But none is giving me what I am looking for.

Is there any solution?

---

**Edit**

So with the development version from GitHub it does compute the effect sizes for the whole factor:

```r
r2beta(mdl, partial = TRUE)
#   Effect   Rsq upper.CL lower.CL
# 1  Model 0.407    0.761    0.172
# 3    age 0.260    0.656    0.034
# 2 gender 0.233    0.638    0.026
```

The problem now is that I need both: for the whole factor *and* for the break down with dummy codes (or any other code). Is there a way to achieve this or do I need to manually create dummy codes? it would be nice to have an option in the function to specify which output we wish.

Comment: I assume you mean `library(lmerTest)` instead of `library(lmer)` and `data = df` instead of `data = DT` in your second `lmer()` call.  If so, I *do* get the effect sizes for the (whole) factors `gender` and `age` with the latest `r2glmm` version from GitHub. What happens if you run restart `R`, then run `remove.packages(c("lmerTest", "r2glmm"))`, then `install.packages("lmerTest"); devtools::install_github("bcjaeger/r2glmm")`, and then execute your code with the adaptions I mentioned?

Comment: @statmerkur It does work now, thanks! I corrected the issues you mentioned. Now the question is, what if I want to get the effect sizes for the dummy code contrasts instead of the whole factor? I need both in fact. Would I need to be switching from one version to the other? That would be extremely cumbersome. There should be an option for that.