# Help with effect sizes in lme4

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, effect-size

I want to compute an effect size for a fixed factor. In this study, there is one fixed factor with 3 conditions (Consistency). Passage and Subject are random effects. I used a Cohen's d to compute effect sizes comparing two means at a time, but I would like to compute an overall effect size of the fixed factor, Consistency.

What effect size measure is appropriate for a design with one IV and 3 conditions in mixed modeling and how would I write the code to carry out the effect size?

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

**Here is the code I used:**

```
PdatFIN$RT_target <- as.numeric(PdatFIN$RT_target)
PdatFIN$Consistency <- as.factor(PdatFIN$Consistency)
str(PdatFIN)
m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage), PdatFIN); summary(m); Anova(m)
lme.dscore(m,data=PdatFIN,type = "lme4")
m.contrasts <- emmeans(m,"Consistency")
pairs(m.contrasts)
```

And here is my output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage)
   Data: PdatFIN

REML criterion at convergence: 7314.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0682 -0.6320 -0.1771  0.5346  4.1376 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 203923   451.6   
 Passage  (Intercept)  23091   152.0   
 Residual             239054   488.9   
Number of obs: 476, groups:  Subject, 30; Passage, 18

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   1711.58      98.75  17.333
Consistency2   427.71      56.19   7.612
Consistency3   173.18      55.99   3.093

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Cnsst2
Consistncy2 -0.301       
Consistncy3 -0.303  0.532
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: RT_target
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Consistency 59.216  2  1.385e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> #Cohens d
> lme.dscore(m,data=PdatFIN,type = "lme4")
                    t       df         d
Consistency2 7.612028 432.5373 0.7320127
Consistency3 3.092820 434.6247 0.2967068
> m.contrasts <- emmeans(m,"Consistency")
> pairs(m.contrasts)
 contrast                    estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Consistency1 - Consistency2     -428 56.2 432  -7.607  <.0001
 Consistency1 - Consistency3     -173 56.1 434  -3.090  0.0060
 Consistency2 - Consistency3      255 54.3 429   4.688  <.0001

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/439842/2126 
?